# How do I check Google Forms checkbox via console?

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

I am writing a script that automatically fills in Google Forms.
I can access checkbox via querySelector, but it has no method .click() or sth like this. What can i do to CHECK CHECKBOXES?

Comment: I tried changing "aria-checked" attribute and inserting isChecked, but it not seems to work..

Comment: Hi! From where ? An extension ? From your devtools ? from a bot ? please add details

Comment: hello! from devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, .click() worked))))

```html
document.querySelector("[data-value='ANSWER']").click()
```